# What is Wolfram engine and can I delete it?

Tags: filesystem, storage, wolfram-engine

I am low on space. Inspectin my store with

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100M -exec ls -la --block-size=M {} \; | sort -nk 5
```

gave me 20 most heavy files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 102M Dez 18 11:58 /opt/pycharm-community-2020.3.1/lib/platform-impl.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116M Nov 16 19:05 /var/cache/apt/archives/scratch3_1.0.6_armhf.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 121M Jul 10  2020 /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.1/SystemFiles/Java/Linux-ARM/lib/modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 121M Nov 28 18:42 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/jmods/java.base.jmod
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 121M Nov 28 18:42 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/lib/modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 136M Nov 10 16:37 /home/pi/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.9.hs-adpt/lib/modules
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 137M Aug  3 03:06 /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.1/SystemFiles/Links/GeometryTools/LibraryResources/Linux-ARM/libGeometryTools.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 138M Nov 18 21:15 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-v7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 139M Nov 18 21:15 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 143M Dez 16 15:26 /opt/pycharm-community-2020.3.1/jbr/lib/libcef.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176M Dez  6 05:09 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-11-jdk-headless_11.0.9.1+1-1~deb10u2_armhf.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 191M Dez 21 21:24 /home/pi/.sdkman/archives/java-11.0.9.hs-adpt.zip
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 266M Jan 16 20:02 /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 300M Jan 16 20:02 /var/log/daemon.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 587M Sep  3 19:21 /var/cache/apt/archives/wolfram-engine_12.1.1+2020081901_armhf.deb
```

Wolfram Engine is the most heavy. I dont use it and dont know what it is. Is it safe to delete it?

Comment: Welcome.  For future reference, *if* you searched online for this first it would be good to reference that and say you are still uncertain based on what you found, otherwise regulars here are bound to point out that a simple internet search would probably have answered your question.  *If you didn't,* keep in mind that we, like other SE sites, do expect you to make **some minimal research effort yourself before you ask a question**.   Anyway, no you do not need it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica  It's installed by default as a sort of promotion.

Comment: `sudo apt purge wolfram*; sudo apt autoremove` will get rid of it. It also means you installed the wrong version of RaspiOS. The full version includes it. The desktop version doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Wolfram** is the programming language of **mathematica**. Don't just delete the files. This may confuse and break your installation system. If you don't need **wolfram** just deinstall it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt purge --auto-remove wolfram*
```

Another simple command in this context to free some storage is:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt clean
```

clean will delete downloaded application packages, and is safe to run - if a package is needed it will just be downloaded again.

Comment: I know i'm lte for the party - but maybe say a word about what clean does?

Comment: clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from /var/cache/apt/archives/ and /var/cache/apt/archieves/partial/. 
This answer is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635646/what-are-the-differences-between-apt-clean-remove-purge-etc-commands